# Every function from discrete metric space to another metric space is uniformly continuous

Tags: limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

My solution:It is fairly straightforward graphically but I just want to ensure if it is rigorous enough.

Suppose $X$ is a discrete metric space and $f$ be any function from $X$ to $Y$ where $Y$ is any other metric space. Let $d_{x}$ and $d_{y}$ denote the metrics in metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

If $p,q\in X, p=q$, then $d_{x}(p,q)=0<\delta$ for any $\delta>0$.
If $p,q\in X, p\neq q$, then $d_{x}(p,q)=1$.

Choosing $\delta=2$, we have $d_{y}(f(p),f(q))<\epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon>0$.

So $\forall \epsilon>0,$ we have $\delta>2$, such that $d_{x}(p,q)<\delta$ implies $d_{y}(f(p),f(q))<\epsilon$.

So, any function from a discrete metric space to any other metric space is uniformly continuous.

Please suggest if it is correct and rigorous enough.

Answer (score 5):

> Choosing $\delta=2$, we have $d_{y}(f(p),f(q))<\epsilon$, $\forall \epsilon>0$.

No, that is wrong, if you choose $\delta = 2$ then $p$ and $q$ can be ANY points in $X$, because the distance between any two points in $X$ is always less than 2. So that won't tell you anything about $d(f(p), f(q))$ at all. If you set $\delta<1/2$ then you force $p=q$ thus obviously $f(p)=f(q)$ so you have uniform continuity.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of uniform continuity that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have a corresponding $\delta>0$? This is satisfied by $\delta=2$ in this case. Can you please explain? I may be wrong.

Comment: I understand your selection of $\delta$ but I am not clear why we can't take $\delta=2$. This may sound trivial but I am taking Maths for the first time. Thanks for bearing with me

Comment: If I take $\delta=2$, then every point can be compared with every other point and hence $d(p,q)=1$ for any $p\neq q$. Hence $d(f(p),f(q))<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$

Comment: @Martin, the point is "for any". If you choose $\delta=2$ then every point in the space is within $\delta$ of any other point so $f^{-1}(y) = X$ for all $y\in Y$. Clearly you can choose some $\epsilon$ so that not every pair of points is within $\epsilon$ of each other. The important thing is that **for all** $\epsilon > 0$. It has to work for any value, even like 0.0001 or 0.00000000001, anything greater than zero.

Comment: Can you please give me an intuition of uniform continuity? I think I am very confused now. I still think $\delta=2$ should satisfy for all $\epsilon$

Comment: I am visualizing it with graph and it seems fine

Comment: @Martin let $X=\mathbb R$ under the discrete metric, and let $Y=\mathbb R$ under the usual metric and let $f$ be the identity function. Let $\epsilon = 0.1$ then if $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1,000,000$, then $d_X(x_1, x_2)=1 < 2$, but $d_Y(x_1, x_2) = |f(0) - f(1,000,000)| > \epsilon$ thus this is not uniformly continuous if $\delta=2$.

Comment: Yes, I get this point. But with $\delta= 1/2$ and with all the functions and metrics as you described now, how does $\delta=1/2$ fit in this? Thanks

Comment: @Martin, the discrete metric means that $d(a,b) = 1$ if $a\neq b$ and $d(a,b)=0$ if $a=b$. If you set $\delta<1/2$ then $d(a,b)<1/2$ is equivalent to $a=b$.

Comment: But in that case, $d(0,10000)=1>1/2$. Isn't it? So, we won't be able to select 2 distinct points

Comment: @Martin, exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

For any $\epsilon>0$, you can choose that $\delta=\frac12$, then for any $x,y \in X$, if $|x-y|<\delta$, then $x=y$, and hence $|f(x)-f(y)|=0<\epsilon$, which shows that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: I added another answer because although this answer is a correct solution, it doesn't address the question asked, which is whether $\delta=2$ is a possible choice.

Comment: @Paul: If I take $\delta=2$, then every point can be compared with every other point and hence $d(p,q)=1$ for any $p\neq q$. Hence $d(f(p),f(q))<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Where am I going wrong with this argument? Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

To show that $f$ is continuous:

Discrete metric induces discrete topology, then preimage of any open set in $Y$ is automatically open in $X$ thus $f$ is continuous. 
(For uniform continuity use the fact that singletons are open as Paul and Suzu. Hirose pointed out earlier.)