# Show that every mapping $f: X \to Y$ is continuous where $(X,d)$ is a metric space with the discrete metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with the discrete metric and let $(Y,d')$ be an arbitrary metric space. Show that every mapping $f: X\to Y$ is continuous.

I got a bit confused about this, initially, I thought that it would come quite directly from the definition, but I'm not sure how to proceed since I'm not given $f$ to work with. Perhaps there is some other definition for continuity that I'm not familiar? I've used the one that states $\forall \varepsilon >0 \ \exists \delta >0$ s.t. $d(x,y) < \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(y) | < \varepsilon.$

Comment: Take $\delta< 1.$ What happens?

Comment: I think you mean $d'(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon$ rather than $|f(x)-f(y) | < \varepsilon$. Also, you _are_ given an $f$ to work with, you just aren't given any more information about it.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1016214/42969

Comment: The discrete metric means $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $1$ otherwise. Thus to prove the continuity, you may choose $\delta=0.5$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hint: What happens if you set $\delta=\frac12$?

Comment: A nine-year member with 170K reputation might sense that this has been asked and answered before ...

Comment: @MartinR Quite right. Yet I am on mobile and have severely limited resources to do the required research. This is IMO the most reasonable way I have to get this question off the unanswered queue.